# SQLCipher join two database tables

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlcipher

I successfully attached DB to another DB using SQLCipher like this:

```
ATTACH DATABASE '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/testApp/files/dbTest1.s3db'
AS dbTest1 KEY 'Password';
```

I am not getting any error. When I try to use this query:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM dbTest1.SaTTest
UNION SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM SatTest
WHERE (Address1 LIKE '%cor%' OR column1 LIKE '%cor%')
```

I am getting this error:

```
I/Database(2587): sqlite returned:
error code = 1, msg = no such table: dbTest1.SaTTest.
```

How can i use alias in attached database tables?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just a typo, it should be `dbTest1.SatTest` instead of `dbTest1.SaTTest`. Please always keep in mind case-sensivity